# How to increase precision for function e^x

Tags: c, recursion

I am learning C and I was asked to compute e^x and compare it with the value given by exp function in math.h
and this is what I did:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
   
 double exponential( double x ,  double n,   double  p ){  
double  i=1;
 if(n<0)
 return i;
 else   
 i=i+(x/p)*(exponential(x,n-0.00001,p+1));}


int main(){                  
   double x,n,p;
 scanf("%lf",&x);
 printf("math.h e^x =     %lf\n",exp(x));
 printf("calculated e^x = %lf\n",exponential(x,1,1));
 return 0;}
```

but I was only getting correct answers up to x = 30 after that its deviating more as I increase x. Can someone tell me how I should change the code for more precision.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code properly. Your code has syntax errors and bad formatting.

Comment: e to the X is a very difficult function to render precise for large X. Using greater precision types and math is the usual approach.

Comment: Using `long double` could help.

Comment: Your function does not return a value in the case of a else.

Comment: @Gerhard when I used  long double its returning " nan " as output and I don't know why and  regarding return a value in case of else , I want my function to run until I reach n <0 so I think its not required to return a value in case of else . Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user You are wrong. Not returning a value is undefined behaviour. The fact the you sometimes get the correct answer is no proof that your code actually work.

Comment: @user if you do not return `i` remove the line `i=i+(x/p)*(exponential(x,n-0.00001,p+1));` since it has no purpose.

Comment: adding `return i;`  after `i=i+(x/p)*(exponential(x,n-0.00001,p+1));` would at least be valid c code and would not influence your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour (compare [If a function returns no value, with a valid return type, is it okay to for the compiler to return garbage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936011/if-a-function-returns-no-value-with-a-valid-return-type-is-it-okay-to-for-the) ).
That is all the explanation needed for any unwanted or unexpected behaviour.
Compare [What is Undefined Behaviour in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020504/what-is-undefined-behaviour-in-c) .

Comment: but when ever I change the code like removing if else and introducing while ( n>0) and returning I , it gives me a segmentation fault and I don't know why and there is no overflow as well

Comment: Then please create a new question on the different problem you have with a program without undefined behaviour.